# How to trim characters from certain patterned words in string?

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following string:

```
string s = "I need drop the 1 from the end of AAAAAAAA1 and BBBBBBBB1"
```

How can I trim the "1" from any 8 character string that ends in a 1? I got so far as to find a working Regex pattern that finds these strings, and I'm guessing I could use a TrimEnd to remove the "1", but how I do I modify the string itself?

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\w{8}1");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(s))
{
    MessageBox.Show(match.Value.TrimEnd('1'));
}
```

The result I'm looking for would be "I need drop the 1 from the end of AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBB"

Comment: Do the eight characters need to be identical?

Comment: If you have a regex to find the characters that need to be removed, then use Regex.Replace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx

Comment: If it's any 8 character string why do you need regex unless you mean substring?

Comment: The 8 characters don't have to be identical. They're table names in a database, so in reality look like "TBLACUST1" or "TBLBPROD1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` is the tool for the job:

```
var regex = new Regex("\\b(\\w{8})1\\b");
regex.replace(s, "$1");
```

I slightly modified the regular expression to match the description of what you are trying to do more closely.

Comment: The "$1" was the part I didn't know how to do. Thank you!! This worked perfectly.

Comment: I'd suggest `new Regex(@"\b(\w{8})1\b")` instead - I find it much easier to read without the double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here a non-regex approach:

```
s = string.Join(" ", s.Split().Select(w => w.Length == 9 && w.EndsWith("1") ? w.Substring(0, 8) : w));
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB with LINQ:

```vb
Dim l = 8
Dim s = "I need drop the 1 from the end of AAAAAAAA1 and BBBBBBBB1"
Dim d = s.Split(" ").Aggregate(Function(p1, p2) p1 & " " & If(p2.Length = l + 1 And p2.EndsWith("1"), p2.Substring(0, p2.Length - 1), p2))
```

Comment: That's fine. I am a VB developer who came to view this question, and there are probably others like me. I pointed the language out at the beginning of my post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
s = s.Replace(match.Value, match.Value.TrimEnd('1'));
```

And the s string will have the value you want.